# Can the word consider be used in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

**This question is very much preferably to be answered by native English speakers**
I've been looking through some text written by Russian native speaker. And I've encountered this phrase: **"Why don’t people consider what they do?"**
I've read this and it feels like something is very wrong with placing "consider" there.
I translated the word from English to my language and I found out that that word also has a meaning "think". But I guess "consider" doesn't fit properly here anyway. At least it sounds very strange for me. I feel like this word has a meaning a bit different from just plain "think" 

Am I right? Or "consider" fits in this context nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fits. It's a synonym in this context of "think about". So, it means

> Why don't people think about what they do?

It's an expression of regret that people do things without considering (thinking about) the likely results.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I don't think (consider ) that I feel the difference, but I will bear that in mind

Comment: Ok; remember there is a difference between "think" and "think about". Only the latter is replaceable by "consider".

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: For example, I can say "I think you like Call of Duty more than Battlefield". There's no "think about" meaning but as I guess it's still replaceable

Comment: No, in that sentence, "consider" doesn't quite work.Also not all cases of "think about" and "consider" are interchangeable. I suggest you look the words up in a few dictionaries, and consider / think about the example sentences.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will